# Scala typeclass not working for parent type

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have the following typeclass:

```
trait Loader[A, B, C] {
  //Any Spark loader requires
  // A -> Input Type
  // B -> Output Type
  // C -> some type of implicit context provided by the compiler from 
  //      the sourounding environment.
  def load(input: A)(implicit context: C): B
}

object Loader {
  implicit object HiveLoader extends Loader[HiveTableSource, DataFrame, HiveContext] {
    def load(source: HiveTableSource)(implicit hc: HiveContext): DataFrame = {
      val db = source.db
      val tbl = source.tbl
      val df =  hc.sql(s"select * from $db.$tbl")
      df
    }
  }

  def loadDataSource[A,B,C](d: A)(implicit ldr: Loader[A,B,C], context: C):B = 
    ldr.load(d)
}

sealed trait DataSource
case class HiveTableSource(db: String, tbl: String) extends DataSource
```

When I try the following, the code fails to compile with "could not find implicit parameter ldr"

```
c // this is of type DataSource

import Loader._ 

loadDataSource(c) //This Fails
```

However if I explicitly force the type

```
LoadDataSource(c.asInstanceof[HiveTableSource]) The code compiles.
```

Comment: What's so surprising about that? `c` is of type `DataSource`; there is no implicit instance of `Loader[DataSource, ?, ?]` in scope; therefore, `loadDataSource(c)` does not compile. Seems logical to me.

Comment: at run time c is a HiveTableSource, be typed as a DataSource for if more sources are added. I am trying to have the typeclass correctly infer the sub type so I dont have to explicitly type with asInstanceOf

Comment: The runtime type of `c` is irrelevant here. If you want to treat it polymorphically as a `DataSource`, then you must have a `Load[DataSource, ?, ?]` in scope. Using `asInstanceOf` negates the benefits of typing it as a `DataSource` in the first place, and is a recipe for desister in general.

Comment: DataSource is generic, there is no concrete implementation of it. I have the typeclasses for the subtypes but do not know how to have scala chose the correct subtype when 'c' is type as a DataSource so it can be polymorphic.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - you can't. Implicit parameters are chosen at compile time - therefore they must match the compile-time type of `c`, not its runtime type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `asInstanceOf` is recipe for disaster. See the ["The Scalazzi Safe Scala Subset"](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7810909/talks/parametricity/4985cb8e6d8d9a24e32d98204526c8e3b9319e33/parametricity.pdf).

However, if you treat `DataSource` as an ADT (algebraic data type), then you could get around this using pattern matching, but you'd have to select the instance of the typeclass yourself.

For that to be possible, there has to be a restrict set of possible data sources (much like `Option[A]` is restricted to `Some[A]` and `None`). I see you've sealed your `DataSource` trait so you should be ok.

```
sealed trait DataSource
final case class HiveTableSource(db: String, tbl: String) extends DataSource
final case class SomeOtherSource() extends DataSource

val c: DataSource = ???

c match {
  case s: HiveTableSource => loadDataSource(s)(HiveLoader)
  case s: SomeOtherSource => loadDataSource(s)(SomeOtherLoader)
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was thinking I would need to do. Huge hep.  In this case, is using typeclasses the right design pattern?

Comment: @user2726995 No problem. I can't tell for sure whether this is the best approach, I'd need the big picture. But I see nothing obviously wrong with it.

Comment: Actually, the pattern match allows s to become typed, and the implicit is worked out correctly without explicitly passing it.